# How to find a matching value for previous year in YYYY-Qx format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this dataset with `['Sales']` values grouped by `['Fiscal Quarter']` in `YYYY-Qx` format. I want to compare the value of a quarter with the same quarter from the previous year (2019-Q2 with 2018-Q2, for example).

I'm doing this the manual way, creating a new column `Prev FY` and shifting values up 4 times to get to the matching value and it's working fine.

`x = 4`

`df['Prev FY'] = df['Sales'].shift(x)`

Sometimes some quarter data is missing, so shifting 4 times no longer does the job. I want to improve the code to automatically find the correct row using the `['Fiscal Quarter']` column.

Any help on this issue?

Comment: Please provide sample data and your expected output, so we can provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) and then use parameter `freq` in [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fiscal Quarter':['2017-Q2','2018-Q2','2019-Q1','2019-Q2'],
                   'Sales':[10,20,30,40]})

df['Fiscal Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fiscal Quarter']).dt.to_period('Q')

df = df.set_index('Fiscal Quarter')
df['Prev FY'] = df['Sales'].shift(4, freq='Q')
print (df)

                Sales  Prev FY
Fiscal Quarter                
2017Q2             10      NaN
2018Q2             20     10.0
2019Q1             30      NaN
2019Q2             40     20.0
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Is it possible to perform it without setting FQ as an index, in FYYY-Qx format, too?

Comment: @currentlyunknown - Not, because `shift` working with `PeriodIndex` or `DatetimeIndex` or `TimedeltaIndex` only.

Comment: I did it! After running your code:
1. reset_index()
2. str(x)[:4].replace('20', 'FY')+'-'+str(x)[-2:] for x in df['Fiscal Quarter'].
Thanks a lot for your help!